# Balanced Data Distributor inserts data one at a time to destination but not parallelly

Tags: ssis

I have used SSIS Balance Data Distributor just to fill 50,000 Records from a OLEDB Source to OLEDB Destination,

When i don't Use SSIS BDD it takes 2 minutes 40 Secs when i use BDD it takes 1 minute 55 Secs which does not make that much difference.

I also find that the data does not load into destination Parallelly it is loading in first destination and later on it fills the next one. (One at a time) Can any of you please help how to fill them parallelly?

Comment: Does your destination table have any indexes on it?  If so, please describe them?  How many / clustered or non clustered.  Are you populating a table in SQL, if so, what version?

Comment: There are no indexes in the table

Comment: Do you have tablock on for each destination? You should since the table is a heap

Comment: Hello Mark,
I have unchecked the Table Lock checkbox in the destination tables.

Answer (score 1):

Balanced Data Distribution is not a silver bullet for performance and runtime.  It is good when:

- You have CPU-intensive transformations, and can benefit from parallel execution
- Your destination supports concurrent insert

The first case is clear and it depends on your dataflow. As for the concurrent insert on OLE DB destination; the best results are on heap tables, or tables without a primary key/clustered index and other indexes as well. Or the clustered key has to defined on autoincremented surrogate key. On OLE DB Destination you might need to disable table lock; otherwise it could prevent insert from being parallel. But check for yourself, as written in Mark's answer - sometimes parallel insert works with table lock, but on a heap table or columnstore.
Other table types (with indexes, cluster or not) might escalate locks to table level or require index rebuilding, effectively disabling parallel insert. Delete or disable it.
So, you have to evaluate yourself weather the parallel execution justifies additional efforts in development and support.

Comment: Hello Ferdi,

its been a long time since i saw your post. Sorry for the delayed respose.
I tried creating Non-Clustered Index and also disabled Tab Lock in destination table. Nothing works. It doesnt run parallely. As i said earlier it executes first destination and then it moves to another.

Comment: @saravankumar, try to remove **all** indexes on the destination table in addition to disabled Table Lock.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using BDD to insert into the same table, you will only get parallel inserts if the table is a heap (no clustered index) and does not have a unique constraint.

If tablock is turned ON for all the destinations, sql will take a special lock (BU), which will allow parallel inserts to the same heap.

If there are no other indexes on the table and the database is NOT in full recovery model, you will gain the additional benefit of minimal logging.

As you noted in your question, using BDD saved you about 45s - it’s actually working. You’ll probably see different performance when running on a server that has more cores and memory, so be sure to test there as well. The measure of success will be total duration, rather than what visual studio displays in its debugger. 
Planning for server execution, it would also be helpful to increase these two properties on the data flow:

-DefaultBufferMaxRows (try adding a 0 to bring it to 100,000)

-DefaultBufferSize - add a zero to max out memory

If you’re on sql 2016, you can instead set AutoAdjustBufferSize to true, which will ignore the above properties and optimize the buffer to the best performance size. 
These adjustments will increase the commit size of the inserts which will result in faster writes to some degree.

The bottom line is keep tablock on, test on the server. BDD is working.